# What to do if my internet connection drops during the exam?

Tags: online

Next week I will start having online exams. One of the rules is that the camera must stay on during the whole time. Unfortunately, my internet connection will occasionally drop. This will happen rarely (maybe a few times a day) and will last from one to a few minutes. I am very worried that if this happens during the exam the professor may be suspicious. What can I do to assure him I'm not cheating?

P.S. I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask, maybe Academia is better?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't have anything to do with the workplace. Ask your school what you should do, we can't tell you what their policies are.

Comment: Almost certainly your school/college/university will have a policy around this - ask them.

Comment: This is an issue I encountered (and suffered for) when taking professional certification exams remotely, and I wish I had planned for it. Not sure this needs to be closed.

Comment: There's an [Academia.se] site.

Comment: Yes, academia is better. You can move this question to there.

Comment: @Andy Even if this was about a professional certification it would be closed for the “specific company policies” reason. We can’t know the rules for what to do if their connection fails because that’s specific to the institution (possibly the school district or board in this case).

Comment: Take the exam somewhere that has a stable internet connection... no idea why you wouldn't, last thing you want to worry about during an exam is an infrastructure problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The right person to ask this of is your professor**

Nobody on any StackExchange site can give you a good answer to this as the policy for this will differ by course and software program used.